# Basic question: how to properly redesign this schema

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

I am hopping on a project that sits on top of a Sql Server 2008 DB with what seems like an inefficient schema to me. However, I'm not an expert at anything SQL, so I am seeking for guidance.

In general, the schema has tables like this:

ID | A | B

- ID is a unique identifier
- A contains text, such as animal names. There's very little variety; maybe 3-4 different values in thousands of rows. This could vary with time, but still a small set.
- B is one of two options, but stored as text. The set is finite.

My questions are as follows:

- Should I create another table for names contained in A, with an ID and a value, and set the ID as the primary key? Or should I just put an index on that column in my table? Right now, to get a list of A's, it does "select distinct(a) from table" which seems inefficient to me.
- The table has a multitude of columns for properties of A. It could be like: Color, Age, Weight, etc. I would think that this is better suited in a separate table with: ID, AnimalID, Property, Value. Each property is unique to the animal, so I'm not sure how this schema could enforce this (the current schema implies this as it's a column, so you can only have one value for each property).

Right now the DB is easily readable by a human, but its size is growing fast and I feel like the design is inefficient. There currently is not index at all anywhere. As I said I'm not a pro, but will read more on the subject. The goal is to have a fast system. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Haha no, I'm not in school anymore ;) And this is not for a veterinary clinic, I just don't want to expose the boring details of what's actually in the DB.

Comment: @user470473 I just wanted to use the veterinary clinic example since it would illustrate table relationships a bit more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a database that might represent a veterinary clinic.

If the table you describe represents the various patients (animals) that come to the clinic, then having properties specific to them are probably best on the primary table. But, as you say column "A" contains a species name, it might be worthwhile to link that to a secondary table to save on the redundancy of storing those names:

For example:

```
Patients
--------
ID  Name   SpeciesID   Color         DOB         Weight
1   Spot   1           Black/White   2008-01-01  20

Species
-------
ID   Species
1    Cocker Spaniel
```

If your main table should be instead grouped by customer or owner, then you may want to add an Animals table and link it:

```
Customers
---------
ID   Name
1    John Q. Sample

Animals
-------
ID   CustomerID   SpeciesID   Name    Color        DOB          Weight
1    1            1           Spot    Black/White  2008-01-01   20

...
```

As for your original column B, consider converting it to a boolean (`BIT`) if you only need to store two states. Barring that, consider `CHAR` to store a fixed number of characters.

Comment: Thanks. The interpretation with a veterinary clinic is fine :)
When saving the redundancy of storing the species name directly in the 'Patients' table, is it only about db size? What about performance? Is it the same if I add an index on that column (storing text, not IDs)?

Comment: Storing references to information that is re-used, such as the species name, will decrease the storage space requirement; it's a small savings but the more records the database has, the more it adds up. Performance-wise I think you would need a very significant number of records to be able to tell the difference. Indexes, correctly used, will always help performance. If you create a parent-child table relationship, then the primary and foreign keys should be indexed. Adding an index to a column that stores repeat text values will probably not add much performance.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, it depends.

By having the animal names directly in the table, it makes your reporting queries more efficient by removing the need for many joins.

Going with something like 3rd normal form (having an ID/Name table for the animals) makes you database smaller, but requires more joins for reporting.

Either way, make sure to add some indexes.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, the way I proposed originally would reduce the db size but make perf worse. I am not concerned by the db size, so I will stick to the current implementation and create an index.